# A novel about a book with pages from another book?

Tags: story-identification, novel

I was shopping for books when I found one that intrigued me.

The story:  A man buys a book and reads it, only to find that the pages are misprinted. So he returns it to the store, and gets a new copy.

The new book is an entirely different story. He goes in search of the previous story, to find out what happens.

Any idea what book this is, or its author?
I think it's a relatively new book(published post 2010).

Comment: I don't have a copy to check this out against but when I read your question I immediately though of Greg Bear's City at the End of Time. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/City_at_the_End_of_Time

Comment: The answer isn't [House of Leaves](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/House_of_Leaves), although the question immediately reminded me of that book.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This sounds like *If on a Winter's Night A Traveller* by Italo Calvino.

I wasn't sure if it qualified as SF&F, but it is mentioned on [isfdb](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?716873).

Here's wikipedia's synopsis ("traveler" in the US)

> *If on a winter's night a traveler* (Italian: *Se una notte d'inverno un
> viaggiatore*) is a 1979 novel by the Italian postmodernist writer Italo
> Calvino. The narrative, in the form of a frame story, is about the
> reader trying to read a book called *If on a winter's night a traveler*.
> Each chapter is divided into two sections. The first section of each
> chapter is in second person, and describes the process the reader goes
> through to attempt to read the next chapter of the book he is reading.
> The second half is the first part of a new book that the reader
> ("you") finds. The second half is always about something different
> from the previous ones and the ending is never explained. The book was
> published in an English translation by William Weaver in 1981.

The books begins with what appears to be *If on a winter's night a traveller*, but chapter 2 continues in the second person.

> ...Wait a minute! Look at the page number. Damn! From page 32 you've
> gone back to page 17! What you thought was a stylistic subtlety on the
> author's part is simply a printer's mistake: they have inserted the
> same pages twice.

You exchange the book for another copy.

> Then from the very first page you realize that the novel you are
> holding has nothing to do with the one you were reading yesterday.